# OutOfMemoryError ao iniciar Activity algumas vezes

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo meu projeto de engenharia de software que consiste em um aplicativo Android e estou com um problema na transição entre Activity.

O problema se baseia em duas telas:

**Tela de login, composta por:**

- Imagen (logo)
- Campo e-mail
- Campo Senha
- Cadastre-se
- Esqueci minha senha

**Tela de recuperação de senha, composta por:**

- Campo e-mail
- Botao enviar

Ok, quando pressiono o botão Enviar da tela de recuperação eu sou redirecionado para a tela de login. Ai que esta o problema, se eu fizer isto três vezes a aplicação para de funcionar.

**Fluxo:**
Login > Recuperação > Login > Recuperação > Login > Recuperação > Login ERRO

Esta é a maneira que estou usando para fazer a transição entre uma activity e outra. Não sei se esta é a certa, fazendo com que a Activity pause e a outra resuma.

```
Intent intentLogin = new Intent(RecuperarActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intentLogin);
```

**Este é o erro gerado:**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24582668 byte allocation    with 16777120 free bytes and 16MB until OOM
```

Parece que ele meio que esta alocando novamente a activity. Fiz um teste e o metodo onResume é chamado normalmente. As outras partes do erro falam sobre BitmapFactory tem relaçao com a imagem que deve pesar, mas mesmo assim eu devo ser capaz de abrir uma tela quantas vezes eu quiser.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Uma solução possível é fazer `finish()` a seguir a `startActivity()`. Veja também se a imagem não é maior do que o necessário

Comment: Você pode estar com vazamento de memória. A Activity ser destruída não significa que o lixo foi recolhido. Ative nas opções de desenvolvedor a opção Não Manter Atividades. Se, mesmo assim, estiver dando o problema, certamente é isso.

Comment: Funcionou amigos. Testei primeiro com a funcionalidade que o Pablo mencionou para ter certeza e depois dei o finish(). Porém fiquem ligados no seguinte. Se eu dou finish na activity do Login, quando estou na tela de recuperação eu nao consigo voltar para o login se não tentar recuperar uma conta. Para isso utilizei 

`intentLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);´

desta maneira eu elimino a pilha de activities quando volto para login.

Comment: @JoãoFelipeGonçalves Não sou muito fã do `finish()` pra resolver isso. Acho que é mais interessante você tentar encontrar a raiz do problema. Um palpite: você possui campos estáticos na sua Activity?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Como uma label? Neste caso tenho duas, "Cadastrar" e "Esqueci minha senha"

Comment: seguindo a resposta do @ramaral de o `finish()` apenas em uma activity que você não vai utilizar mais, como a sua tela de recuperar senha, e a tela de login já que é uma tela que entra em espera para que outra activity seja executada antes de voltar para ela você pode coloca-la em `onResume()` (ciclo de vida da activity), olhe a resposta para essa minha pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115564/atualizar-listview-usando-notifydatasetchanged/115575#115575 eu sempre volto para essa tela após uma alteração na lista.

Comment: Se tu colocar a uma imagem grande ou na pasta errada. tu vai gerar esse erro. Poste o stacktrace