# Atualizar ListView com notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, arraylist, android-adapter

Boa tarde pessoal, eu não estou conseguindo usar o `notifyDataSetChanged()` para atualizar o meu ListView.

A minha aplicação pega os dados inseridos no Banco de dados e lista na página de cadastro, logo após, se o usuário clicar em um item ele pode ser alterado, porém, depois de ser alterado é necessário sair da página e entrar novamente para o List View ser atualizado.

Tentei usar o `notifyDataSetChange()` mas não consegui. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Main Activity com o ListView:

```
public ArrayList<modelListprod> listadeprod;
public static AdapterProd itensprod;
private ListView listproduto;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( layout.activity_main);
        layoutContentMain = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById( id.layoutContentMainMenu);
        conectarBanc();
        selecionaemitente(conexao);

        listadeprod = new ArrayList<modelListprod>();
        itensprod = new AdapterProd(this, listadeprod);

        listproduto = (ListView) findViewById(id.listproduto);
        listproduto.setAdapter(itensprod);

    }

public void atualizalistaprod(){
        itensprod.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



public void lprod(SQLiteDatabase db){
        ArrayList<modelListprod> prod = new ArrayList<modelListprod>();

        //Passa para dentro do while
        //listprod = new modelListprod();

        String descricao = "";
        String ean = "";
        String status = "";
        Double precoprod;
        String categoria;
        int cod;

        final SQLiteDatabase d5 = dadosOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        final Cursor cursor5 = d5.query("produto" , new String[]{"descricao", "ean", "status", "precoprod", "codigocateg", "cod"},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
        if (cursor5 != null) {
            if (cursor5.moveToFirst()) {

                do {

                    //uma nova instância por cada registo
                    listprod = new modelListprod();

                    descricao = cursor5.getString(0);
                    ean = cursor5.getString(1);
                    status = cursor5.getString(2);
                    precoprod = cursor5.getDouble(3);
                    categoria = cursor5.getString(4);
                    cod = cursor5.getInt(5);
                    listprod.setDescricao(descricao);
                    listprod.setCategoria(categoria);
                    listprod.setEan(ean);
                    listprod.setPreco(precoprod);
                    listprod.setStatus(status);
                    listprod.getId(cod);

                    //Adiciona ao array
                    listadeprod.add(listprod);

                } while (cursor5.moveToNext());
            }

            listproduto.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    modelListprod c = (modelListprod) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlteraProd.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Dados", (Serializable) c);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        itensprod.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Passa para dentro do while
        //listadeprod.add(listprod);

        AdapterProd adapterProd = new AdapterProd(this, listadeprod);
        listproduto.setAdapter(adapterProd);
    }
```

Meu Adaptador do ListView:

```
public class AdapterProd extends ArrayAdapter<modelListprod> {

    MainActivity m = new MainActivity();

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<modelListprod> lista;



    public AdapterProd(Context context, ArrayList<modelListprod> lista){
        super(context, 0, lista);
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final modelListprod itemposicao = this.lista.get(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.list_prod, null);
        }

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao2);
        textView1.setText(itemposicao.getDescricao());

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvcategoria2);
        textView2.setText(itemposicao.getCategoria());

        TextView textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvpreco2);
        textView3.setText(itemposicao.getPreco().toString());

        TextView textView4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvean2);
        textView4.setText(itemposicao.getEan());

        TextView textView5 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvstatus2);
        textView5.setText(itemposicao.getStatus());

        Button grava = (Button) convertView.findViewById( R.id.gravaalteraprod );
        grava.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemposicao.setDescricao( itemposicao.getDescricao());
                itemposicao.setCategoria( itemposicao.getCategoria());
                itemposicao.setPreco( itemposicao.getPreco());
                itemposicao.setEan( itemposicao.getEan());
                itemposicao.setStatus( itemposicao.getStatus());
                m.atualizalistaprod();

            }
        } );



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse método `lprod` tá sendo chamando onde?

Comment: O método lprod está em um outro botão da minha Main, ele apenas chama a tela com o listview preenchido, o problema mesmo ta sendo após alterar o item. Ele altera normalmente, porém o listview não atualiza após ser alterado, é necessário fechar a abrir a tela novamente.

Comment: No seu caso você quer atualizar apenas 1 linha do seu ListView neh? Infelizmente não sei responder pro seu caso, mas talvez esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16453407/10526030) te ajude. Sua pergunta é muito boa.

Comment: Isso, toda vez que eu alterasse algo no meu banco de dados eu queria que atualizasse o meu listview sem precisar sair e entrar na tela novamente. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou estudar a fundo e assim que tiver uma solução irei postar aqui.

Comment: Conseguiu com minha resposta? eu testei aqui e pra mim funcionou bem

Comment: Me desculpe a demora para responder. Seu código me ajudou bastante, porém não funcionou na minha aplicação, identifiquei o erro. No meu "convertview" eu coloco que ele tem que tem que buscar o layout do "list_prod" e no meu setOnClickListener eu coloco um evento no botão "gravaralteraprod" que está em outro layout, no caso o layout "alteraprod". O meu continua com esse probleminha, mas estou identificando uma forma de soluciona-lo. Por outro lado, a sua resposta está certíssima, eu que acabei não prestando muita atenção, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [atualizar ListView usando notifyDataSetChanged();](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115564/atualizar-listview-usando-notifydatasetchanged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu adapter dentro do Onclick deixe o seguinte:

```
        itemposicao.setDescricao(itemposicao.getDescricao());
        itemposicao.setCategoria(itemposicao.getCategoria());
        itemposicao.setPreco(itemposicao.getPreco());
        itemposicao.setEan(itemposicao.getEan());
        itemposicao.setStatus(itemposicao.getStatus());
        //remove o item do seu model
        lista.remove(position);
        //e adiciona na mesma posição o item editado
        lista.add(position, itemposicao);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Acho que assim já é capaz da sua listview ser atualizada.